# bash and multiline PS1

Tags: bash

\n in PS1 works fine, but when you try to type a command which takes more than one line, you type second line over the first and when you want to edit the part of such command that normally should be on the line above, the cursor goes at the line above it. Is there any cure for it, or bourne shell just wasn’t born for PS1 with newlines?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ bind -v
set bind-tty-special-chars on
set blink-matching-paren on
set byte-oriented off
set completion-ignore-case off
set completion-map-case off
set convert-meta off
set disable-completion off
set echo-control-characters on
set enable-keypad off
set enable-meta-key on
set expand-tilde off
set history-preserve-point off
set horizontal-scroll-mode off
set input-meta on
set mark-directories on
set mark-modified-lines off
set mark-symlinked-directories on
set match-hidden-files on
set menu-complete-display-prefix off
set meta-flag on
set output-meta on
set page-completions on
set prefer-visible-bell on
set print-completions-horizontally off
set revert-all-at-newline off
set show-all-if-ambiguous off
set show-all-if-unmodified off
set skip-completed-text off
set visible-stats off
set bell-style audible
set comment-begin #
set completion-display-width -1
set completion-prefix-display-length 0
set completion-query-items 100
set editing-mode emacs
set history-size 500
set keymap emacs
```

The modified prompt:

```
PS1="\[\033[01;34m\]\w\n\
\[\033[01;37m\]\]\
\`if [ \u != $LOGIN_NAME ]; then
    echo -n '\u'
fi\`\
\[\033[01;32m\]\
@\
\`if [ '\h' = '$MY_MACHINE' ]; then
    echo -n 'home'
else 
    echo -n '\h'
fi\`\
 \$ \[\033[00m\] "
```

Comment: `powershell_ise` ... Shift+Enter ?

Comment: Bash 4.2.24 (on Ubuntu 12.04) works well with a multiline PS1. Can you post the output of `bash --version` and `bind -v`?

Comment: @sttr I use native bash in native environment

Comment: @jaume updated my post with output of those comands

Comment: Your `bind` configuration looks OK, which terminal are you using? I use xterm (it is the output of `echo $TERM`).

Comment: Have you tried a minimal prompt without colors etc. to make sure it's not a side effect of something else? Maybe it's just confusing the shell due to length calculation with non-printing characters.

Comment: @jaume it is urxvt

Comment: @daniel-beck Uhm… I actually found this bug while trying to customize my prompt string. In just slightly modified standard PS1 with newline, lines do not overlap. I added the code I tried to modify prompt with, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Have you considered moving most of this into `$PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: The second line of your `PS1` appears to have an extra `\]` at the end.

Comment: @daniel-beck Since I’m not sure it will not affect other prompts (PS2-4) I’ll be keeping it in PS1.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! Overlooked this. Fixed and multiline prompt works.

Comment: @karma-fusebox actually it is no final version and was edited many times, I just copypasted last working version from emacs. Code will be brushed and maybe some functions will be made from what is calling there in subshells.

Comment: Nevermind, I deleted the comment because it what was wrong anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt string contained an extra "]" that was affecting how it was displayed.